# jquery datatables static rownumber

Tags: jquery, datatables

I have jquery datatables where first column is rownumber and others are sortable columns. I would like to get this row number as "static", so when sorting table the row number would still keep going 1,2,3,4 no matter how the table is sorted.

now when I sort by other column, the row number changes with the row, ie. 3,1,2,4...

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/6r4bfh4L/8/ added where trying to run some tests

Comment: solved, I don't know yet the details and logic behind this but https://www.datatables.net/examples/api/counter_columns.html has the solution, I were looking with wrong keywords.

Comment: Please post your solution as an answer not as a comment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

looks like @flawlessdiamond found the solution. I will just post the solution with relevant code for others that might need this answer.

So the solution is this:

```
var t = $('#example').DataTable( {
    "columnDefs": [ {
        "searchable": false,
        "orderable": false,
        "targets": 0
    } ],
    "order": [[ 1, 'asc' ]]
} );
t.on( 'order.dt search.dt', function () {
    t.column(0, {search:'applied', order:'applied'}).nodes().each( function (cell, i) {
        cell.innerHTML = i+1;
    } );
} ).draw();
```

Here is also a working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9fc3hj4L/)

Comment: Excellent. This helped in my project :)

Answer (score 0):

I have another solution.

I use columndef attribute. The solution is simple, i take the current start index value, plus current row number, plus 1.  This solution do not need redraw all table each time.

```
columnDefs: [
        {
            "targets": 0,
            "searchable": false,
            "orderable": false,
            "data": null,
            "title": 'No.',
            "render": function (data, type, full, meta) {
                return meta.settings._iDisplayStart + meta.row + 1; 
            }
]
```